Compiling with AJC in IntelliJ giving error
I'm trying to compile a program using AspectJ in IntelliJ, but I'm getting the error message ajc: unrecognized single argument: "-proc:none". I'm also getting an error message that says Internal Error: Bad Args, though I assume that one of these errors is downstream of the other.
-proc:none does not appear anywhere in my project, and I don't see what I can edit to effect this.
My pointcut is
@AfterReturning(
  pointcut = "execution(Square[][] Main.gameplayLoop ())",
  returning = "grid"
)

if that matters.

Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you.

Please make sure that AspectJ plugin is installed and enabled. Also, try with the latest IntelliJ release, if not already. If it doesn't help, please file an issue here and provide your IDE logs for further investigation.
